# SQL distinct on Date and ignore Time

Tags: mysql, sql

I would love to distinct the table below based on `Dates` only and at the same time there is an average of value taken. Is there a way to do so?

```
SELECT DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT(Date, '%Y-%m-%d'),
      AVG(value) AS Timestamp 
FROM abc GROUP BY Date
```

Table abc

```
+--------------------+-------+
| Date               | value |
+--------------------+-------+
| 18-Nov-2013 12:34  |   5   |
| 19-Nov-2013 14:45  |   4   |
| 20-Nov-2013 15:11  |   3   |
| 21-Nov-2013 08:33  |   2   |
| 21-Nov-2013 11:11  |   7   |
| 21-Nov-2013 15:15  |   8   |
+--------------------+-------+
```

Comment: Dates in (my) sql adhere to a specific format

Comment: Do you mean the table structure? If it is, I need the time in table but just one of the query to ignore the time.

Comment: No. I mean you could consider taking a little time to understand the importance of data types in SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use GROUP function

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(Date, '%Y-%m-%d') AS Timestamp, AVG(value)
FROM abc
GROUP BY DATE(Date)
```

Comment: Wooohoooo you're my saviour, the solution here is `GROUP BY DATE(Date)`

Answer (score 2):

you can do this in this way :

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(Dat, '%Y-%m-%d') AS dt,
       Avg(val)                     AS Timestamp
FROM   abc
GROUP  BY dt
```

you can `group by` by evaluated column using its alias in MySQL like I did in above query. Some DBMS like SQL Server doesn't allow such SQL so in that case you can use either subquery or group by function like :

```
SELECT dt,
       Avg(val)
FROM   (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(Dat, '%Y-%m-%d') AS dt,
               val
        FROM   abc) t
GROUP  BY dt 

SELECT DATE_FORMAT(Dat, '%Y-%m-%d') AS datetime,
       Avg(val)                     AS Timestamp
FROM   abc
GROUP  BY DATE_FORMAT(Dat, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0154c/4)

Comment: yeah.. there are many ways to do that. it is also the same thing like `SELECT DATE(Date) AS Timestamp, AVG(value) FROM abc GROUP BY DATE(Date)`..